# Convert Italic XML Tags into WordML Tags

Tags: xml, xslt, wordml

I simply need to transforma XML document into a WordML document (if it is possible to call it simple!) with this form (without processing instructions):

```
<body>
    <p>
        <r>This is the <italic>standard</italic> text run.</r> 
    </p>
</body>
```

The transformed XML should look like this, as per an WordML document:

```
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>This is the </w:t> 
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:i/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>standard</w:t> 
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t> text run.</w:t> 
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

How should i create the XSLT transformation for properly handle the Italic tags??..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="some:w" exclude-result-prefixes="w">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="body">
  <w:body>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </w:body>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p/r/text()">
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t><xsl:value-of select="."/></w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p/r/italic/text()">
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:i/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t><xsl:value-of select="."/></w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<body>
    <p>
        <r>This is the <italic>standard</italic> text run.</r>
    </p>
</body>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<w:body xmlns:w="some:w">
   <w:p>
      <w:r>
         <w:t>This is the </w:t>
      </w:r>
   </w:p>
   <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
         <w:i/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
         <w:t>standard</w:t>
      </w:r>
   </w:p>
   <w:p>
      <w:r>
         <w:t> text run.</w:t>
      </w:r>
   </w:p>
</w:body>
```

Comment: I AM SO MUCH honored, Dimitre, for your answer... I could say i've learned XSL because of your answers here on StackOverflow.com!!.

Nevertheless im still totally confused by the identity transform. In the example, the _p/r/_ clauses handle well the formatting, but i cant figure out how to handle slightly complex uses of tags.

By the way, i've assigned the answer to Mads, because he was few seconds early in here :).

Comment: @hypfco, You are welcome. As for more difficult situations -- please, ask new questions :)

Comment: @hypfco, And you don't really need an identity template for the current problem.

Answer (score 1):

For input as simple as the example provided, the following stylesheet would work. Using a modified [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with specialized templates for the `<italics>` and `r/text()`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <w:body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </w:body>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r/text()">
      <w:p>
          <w:r>
              <w:t><xsl:value-of select="."/></w:t> 
          </w:r>
      </w:p>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r/italic">
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:i/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t><xsl:value-of select="."/></w:t> 
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: THANKS for the prompt response. Thanks for the wikipedia link also. I've study your code to apply it under my case. I'll also check those identity transforms...........